# C++ std string different between debug and release dynamic library

Tags: c++, dll

I have a dynamic library in which I send an IP address and try to connect to an instrument. The library is working well when it's build in debug mode but crashes on using release one.

I am trying to use it from a console application and this is what I have:

Main in the console application

```
#define QT_API extern "C"  __declspec(dllimport)
int main()
{

    QT_InterfaceManager * manager = createInstance();

    cout << "Connect = " << bert_Connect(manager, "172.16.109.113") << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Interface from my dll

```
#define QT_API extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)
#define STACKMODE   __stdcall

QT_API bool STACKMODE bert_Connect(QT_InterfaceManager * inst, std::string IP) {

    cout << "Received IP = " << IP << endl;
    //  Do Something
}
```

When using my function from a Debug library

[image: IP when using Debug]

When using my function from a Release library

[image]

[image]

What might cause such a difference in passing a simple std string

Comment: `The library is working well when it's build in debug mode` Are you sure its not Undefined behaviour?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 No I actually have other functions and all of them are working as expected. Never have I encountered an error while using the debug library.

Comment: Is the function signature the same when called from `main`? I notice you are defining `QT_API` again in `main`. Have you also included `STACKMODE`?

Comment: @JackHughes Yes they are the same. I actually have a preprocessor flag to switch between dllimport and dllexport so that the signature stays the same

Comment: @JackHughes I was able to solve it. The problem is that I am using extern "C" while using an std::string input. When I used `char * IP` instead of `std::string IP` it worked.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 How is it possible that a string is passed correctly in a debug mode while not in a release one. Due to the usage of `extern C` both should not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the caller and the DLL must be built with the same mode type. For example you have function that takes std::string as an argument that is exported from a DLL. If the caller main() is not also compiled in DEBUG it will crash. The compile mode changes the storage definition (secretly) for std:string. So the DEBUG mode definition for std::string in DEBUG mode is different from the definition in release mode. The called function does not agree on the meaning / layout of std::string.
This is likely going to cause a crash.
I suggest passing your string to the dll as a raw pointer. use string.c_str() and consume it as a const char*. This should be fine.

e.g.

QT_API bool STACKMODE bert_Connect(QT_InterfaceManager * inst, const char* IP)

Although since QT_InterfaceManager  is opaque it may have similar problems.